# Question on faulty logic on proving theorem of continuity

Tags: calculus, proof-verification

So, basically, I was reading a theorem that wanted to prove that every polynomial is continuous but for some reason, I think the logic is faulty.

**Theorem 1.4.** If $P(x)$ is a polynomial of degree $n \geq 0$ and if $a$ is a real number, then $P(x)$ is a function that is continuous at $x=a$.

Now, here is another theorem that Theorem 1.4 is based on.

**Theorem 1.2.** If $P(x)$ is a polynomial and if $a$ is a real number, then $\lim_{x \to a} P(x)$ exists and is equal to $P(a)$.

Also, a function is continuous at a point $a$ if it respects these 3 conditions: $f(a)$ exists, $\lim_{x \to a} f(x)$ exists, and $\lim_{x \to a} f(x) = f(a)$.

So, here's how Theorem 1.4 is proven:

With Theorem 1.2 we have $\lim_{x \to a} P(x) = P(a)$ for every real number $a$. As a result, the function $P(x)$ is defined at $x=a$, $\lim_{x \to a} P(x)$ exists, and $\lim_{x \to a} P(x) = P(a)$, so the function $P(x)$ is continuous at $x=a$.

The main problem with this proof, in my opinion, is that it relies on Theorem 1.2 which is faulty. Theorem 1.2 says that if we want to find the limit of a polynomial we just have to evaluate the polynomial in question. In other words, Theorem 1.2 assumes that a polynomial will always be continuous. So, how come can we use Theorem 1.2 to prove Theorem 1.4, considering that we should have proven in the first place that polynomial is always continuous.

Am I right? Or am I in error?

Thank you!

Comment: Theorem 1.2 doesn't assume that a polynomial is a continuous; its proof (which you have omitted) proves that it is continuous.

Comment: @angryavian Is that not an answer to the question?

Comment: why do you don't use $\varepsilon-\delta$ arguments?

Comment: So, this means that theorem 1.4 is useless because we have already proved that a polynomial is continuous with theorem 1.2 ? By the way, I didn't see the "ε−δ" arguments.

Comment: @Astroman Pretty much. You can see this is the case by how the proof of 1.4 is written.

Comment: Ok, then this must be some kind of error from the author. Thank you!